# Mailing list "To:" field at destination no longer shows all recipients

Tags: mailing-list

When a mail is sent to a mailing list and contains other recipients in the To: as well as Cc: fields, the *list members* receiving the mail cannot see who else was specified in the To: field. The Cc: field remains intact.

Is that normal or is it a bug of this specific mailserver?

I have had trouble finding a document describing how a list should work at that level.

Comment: On one of the computer in problem can you validate what the email header look like  ? You can show it in Outlook, but not sure what app your users use.

Comment: @yagmoth555 The headers don't contain more or less info than what I described. What are you looking for?

Comment: I'am looking to see if the header is ok, while not showing ok in the email client

Comment: Depends on your mailing list software, but it's not really unexpected. The To: header really shouldn't be changed, but some do it anyway.